# run on java file runs again the previously executed file

Tags: java

I'm trying to run the following code in Eclipse, but in the last runs, another java file is being executed again, but the below class file not running. Any idea why this is happening? I'm using Eclipse Mars 2

```
package DeclareandAccessControl;

class Cup {}
class Poisoncup extends Cup{
public static void takeCup(Cup c){
if (c instanceof Poisoncup){
    System.out.println("Conceivable");
}else if(c instanceof Cup){
    System.out.println("Dizziying Intellect");
}
else{
    System.exit(0);
}
}
public static void main(String args[]){
Cup cup = new Poisoncup();
takeCup(cup);
 }
}
```

Comment: Try clean and build.

Comment: are you running only this file or this is part of a project ?

Comment: I ran only this file. It works now if I run as Java application!

Answer (score 0):

Press small arrow near the `run` button on toolbar. Here you will see all last used run configurations:

[image]

If you new java file does't shown here it's mean that you never run it before. Then right click on the file in the package explorer and select "Run As => Java application". And it runs and then next time show up in this list.